# AZURE Web App Service Plan and AKS Cluster in same Subscription possible?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-aks, subscription

In a single AZURE Subcription we have a single Application Gateway - managed by AKIC, with AKS Cluster, and a Web App Service Plan for Web App that runs always, the AKS Cluster is elastic.

**TL;DR**

- We encountered an issue with `AzureIngressProhibitedTarget`object that needs to be added to Kubernetes cluster, as otherwise the shared Application GateWay configs are getting deleted.
- Without going into all the details, some of our experts are saying we need an AZURE  Subscription with only AKS and a separate AZURE Subscription with only Web Apps.
- I cannot find such a statement on learn.microsoft.
- My view is we should be able to do this in a single Subscription.
- My view is it should be achievable, and if I introduce a 2nd Application Gateway in the Subscription, it should be OK, but that is not part of the Landing Zone Strategy.

> Basically, can someone point me to AZURE documentation stating
> separate Subscriptions needed when AKS and Web App Service Plan needed
> for a business application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to place them in 2 separate subscriptions.

But you cannot attach the same Application Gateway to an Azure App Service and an AKS Cluster at the same time. One integrates via a private endpoint, the other via an ingress controller.

Integration with AKS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-overview

Integration with App Service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking/app-gateway-with-service-endpoints

So your solution with 2 application gateways would work. You could place traffic manager in front of your 2 application gateway instances: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-load-balancing-azure

Comment: Reading with a colleague we cannot see from the links the restriction you quote. One stated it is possible and an Avenade person stated as well. However, no one got it working.